# How to setup a kubernetes cluster in the purely IPV6 setting?

Tags: kubernetes

I have two PCs, `A` is with Windows 10 installed, `B` is with Ubuntu 20.04 installed.
In general, `A` and `B` are in the different local networks, for example, `A` is in `10.0.7.X`, `B` is in `10.1.7.X`, and they can not ping each other successfully, but they can visit each other by IPV6 address.

Now I want to setup a cluster in these two PCs, `A` is the `master` node and the `B` is the `slave` node.
In `A`, I have installed the `Hyper-V` and installed a `Ubuntu 20.04` in the `Hyper-V` virtual machine and I can setup an `IPV4` based Kubernetes cluster when putting them in the same local network (e.g., `10.0.7.X`).

Now I'm trying to setup the cluster in purely IPV6 setting. I've tried the following command:

```
kubeadm init \
--apiserver-advertise-address=2400:dd01:1032:7:4070:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX\
--pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 \
--image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers \
--cri-socket /var/run/dockershim.sock \
--feature-gates IPv6DualStack=true
```

and add the network manager based on

```
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/canal.yaml -O
kubectl apply -f canal.yaml
```

and the outputs of `kubectl get pods -A` are:

```
root@master:~# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-8f59968d4-jsw55   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          65s
kube-system   canal-gwgjw                               0/2     CrashLoopBackOff    2          66s
kube-system   coredns-6c76c8bb89-6xjc2                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          98s
kube-system   coredns-6c76c8bb89-ww6cg                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          98s
kube-system   etcd-master                               1/1     Running             0          104s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master                     1/1     Running             0          104s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master            1/1     Running             0          104s
kube-system   kube-proxy-nd9bt                          1/1     Running             0          98s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master                     1/1     Running             0          104s
```

and the outputs of `systemctl status kubelet` is:

```
  ubuntu@master:~$ systemctl status kubelet
  ● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
               └─10-kubeadm.conf
       Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-10-19 18:24:59 CST; 1min 24s ago
         Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
     Main PID: 98042 (kubelet)
        Tasks: 24 (limit: 4657)
       Memory: 43.6M
       CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
               ├─ 98042 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_co>
               └─100328 /opt/cni/bin/calico

  10月 19 18:26:17 master kubelet[98042]: I1019 18:26:17.206835   98042 topology_manager.go:219] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: 8b35778f95a8f3fed7e15a1d29456f6067bba1e827ca584f1474e073a085b41e
  10月 19 18:26:17 master kubelet[98042]: I1019 18:26:17.213580   98042 topology_manager.go:219] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: a8b573738e9b72c47c55f49b6946812206251770a4d8490002a04e80991680ef
  10月 19 18:26:17 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:17.225830   98042 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod fcdd3939-7388-4308-bad6-bd419adcd039 ("canal-gwgjw_kube-system(fcdd3939-7388-4308-bad6-bd419adcd039)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-flannel" with >
  10月 19 18:26:22 master kubelet[98042]: W1019 18:26:22.801044   98042 cni.go:333] CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: cannot find network namespace for the terminated container "ea68e0f25fbd137253c572e36bcb9cc9a29ebb4850571411a3ed55a5858f4ebc"
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: W1019 18:26:23.828962   98042 cni.go:333] CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: cannot find network namespace for the terminated container "8f789a2f1bd4d9d6a6f590b6cbb218b2dda0589ce30242efbf8391e596f4050b"
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:23.922994   98042 cni.go:387] Error deleting kube-system_calico-kube-controllers-8f59968d4-jsw55/ea68e0f25fbd137253c572e36bcb9cc9a29ebb4850571411a3ed55a5858f4ebc from network calico/k8s-pod-network: error getting ClusterI>
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:23.925412   98042 remote_runtime.go:140] StopPodSandbox "ea68e0f25fbd137253c572e36bcb9cc9a29ebb4850571411a3ed55a5858f4ebc" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = networkPlugin cni failed to teardown>
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:23.925499   98042 kuberuntime_manager.go:898] Failed to stop sandbox {"docker" "ea68e0f25fbd137253c572e36bcb9cc9a29ebb4850571411a3ed55a5858f4ebc"}
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:23.925575   98042 kuberuntime_manager.go:677] killPodWithSyncResult failed: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "bab09661-da02-414f-8faa-ccb02c8267dd" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = networkPlugin c>
  10月 19 18:26:23 master kubelet[98042]: E1019 18:26:23.925617   98042 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod bab09661-da02-414f-8faa-ccb02c8267dd ("calico-kube-controllers-8f59968d4-jsw55_kube-system(bab09661-da02-414f-8faa-ccb02c8267dd)"), skipping: failed to "KillPodSandb>
  ubuntu@master:~$
```

Does anybody know how to setup a kubernetes cluster in purely ipv6 setting? Thanks.

Comment: What about describing those failing pods ? It should give you more specific information why they cannot be successfully created.

Comment: @mario, thanks a lot for your kind comment. I may find a possible solution in https://github.com/leblancd/kube-v6